# Challenging Joint Probability Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is quite a challenging question I've been having trouble with lately and seems to be an atypical example of a joint distribution question - While I can derive the marginal density of $X$ simply from the uniform distribution, I am at a loss for how the marginal density for $Y$ and the joint density may be derived. Any suggestions would be enormously appreciated!

John wakes 6 AM each morning and then lies in bed for up to 3 hours. After getting up he takes one hour to get ready for work. After that, John likes to play computer games until he goes to work. However he never leaves after 11 AM. For the 3 hours he lies in bed, John is equally likely to get up at any time within that timeframe (uniformly distributed). Also, from the from the time he begins playing computer games and 11 AM, John is equally likely to go to work at any time during that timeframe.

Suppose $X$ is the time John lies in bed, and $Y$ the number of hours from waking to the moment he left home. Find the following:

a. Determine the marginal density of $X$.

b. Determine the marginal density of $Y$ .

c. Determine the $f(y, x)$.

d. Determine the $f(y|x)$.

Update 1:

The marginal density for $y$ I obtained, using the uniform distribution: $f(y)=1/(4-x)$, however I am a little confused as why it is in terms of $x$. Could this be the joint distribution?

(sorry still havent figured out how to use LaTeX on this site!)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the quantity you computed, $1/(4-x)$ is not the marginal for $Y$ but the density of $Y$ **given** the value of $X$, that is, it is $f(y|x)$ (one has to be really careful about the $x$ and $y$ intervals for which this density is valid).

From the above you can henceforth compute $f(x,y)=f(y|x)f(x)$ and the marginals by integration.

The marginals are
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}, \text{ for } 0\le x \le 3,$$
and 
$$f(y) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } 0\le y \le 1\\
\frac{1}{3}\log{\frac{4}{5-y}}, & \text{if } 1\le y\le 4\\
\frac{1}{3}\log{4} & \text{if } 4\le y \le 5.
\end{cases} $$

See if you can arrive at them through integration. I strongly suggest you make a bidimensional plot of the regions for which $f(x,y)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Hi Alonso, thanks for your help that greatly elucidates things, Im working on intervals and integrating. Could you possibly reformat your marginal for f(y), it is still in code?

Comment: Fixed the array code

Comment: Hi Alonso. thanks for your guidance, I can understand why x is bounded by (0,3) and but I am having difficulty understanding how integrating the joint pdf will result in a piecemeal function

Comment: Because the conditional $f(y|x)$ is only defined for $x+1 \le y \le 5$, and so is the joint pdf, with $0 \le x \le 3$. The $xy$ region on which $f(x,y)\neq 0$ is not a square but a trapezoid, this is the origin of the piecewise function; when integrating in the $x$ direction you have to take the geometry of the region into account.